# return values order of Teams GraphAPI

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Do you know the return values using Graph API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams) in what order?

Comment: What means `in what order`?

Comment: Please treat the order as random. We don't want developers depending on the implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

To get the List joinedTeams value, you could use the `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams` in [MS graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer/).

[image]

The required permissions:

[image]
For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Comment: By using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams, O365 returns All team information which I join.
My question is, in which order O365 returns Team name as return value.

*Order which team was created 

*Order which latest conversation have

*Order which Teams name ascending

It want to know the order policy.